# Why Mysql doesn't complete importing all the source data?

Tags: mysql, import

My original csv file contains 7,009,729 rows, the import result completed only 37488 rows, the import did not throw any error, I manually checked the data source in particular the line 37488 and 37489, I don't see any anomaly there. My import script is as following:

```
load data local infile '/root/Downloads/2008flight.csv' into table 2008flight
 fields terminated by ','
 enclosed by '"'
 lines terminated by '\n'
 (Year,
Month,
DayofMonth,
DayOfWeek,
DepTime,
CRSDepTime,
ArrTime,
CRSArrTime,
UniqueCarrier,
FlightNum,
TailNum,
ActualElapsedTime,
CRSElapsedTime,
AirTime,
ArrDelay,
DepDelay,
Origin,
Dest,
Distance,
TaxiIn,
TaxiOut,
Cancelled,
CancellationCode,
Diverted,
CarrierDelay,
WeatherDelay,
NASDelay,
SecurityDelay,
LateAircraftDelay);
```

Comment: How did you manually check the data source? If you are using a text editor that doesn't support large text files, it may not display past 37488 rows.

Comment: There are quite a lot of editors capable doing that: UltraEdit, Notepad++, EmEditor, HxD... they all allow you to examine hex code which is very important in some case

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that. Just asking if you were using one that wasn't compatible to try to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, it is confirmed the import failed because of the raw csv file has a comma in every line's ending, I used notepad++ to find and replace all the ending comma and reprocessed the import with all the rows imported. Thanks.

Comment: that ending comma was not shown in your screen shot.

Comment: I fixed my issue using LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' instead of just \n

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there are some non-printable characters (including `\r\n`) near the Lines 37488 and 37489?  You can use an editor that can display non-printable characters (such as Notepad++) or the unix utility program `od` to examine that.

Comment: That was what I suspected, but I checked the data with hex editor, all rows end with 0A which means \n, you can see the screenshot here [link](https://snag.gy/pB7e3a.jpg)

Comment: I could only see five rows in your screenshot.  But I noticed that Line 37488 has last five fields with numbers (`0,0,0,0,42`), while the other four rows has `NA, NA, NA, NA, NA`.  Could this be a problem? What is the schema for `2008flight`?

Comment: Thank you, I believe I have found the cause! There is an ending comma in every row!!!, I think the ending comma must be removed before the data loading, I am removing all the ending comma now and do the whole process again, hopefully resolve this case.